# Can I write a module for azurerm_marketplace_agreement that will conditionally accept the term if they do not already exist?

Tags: terraform, azure-rm

Good morning all,

I've written a module to accept the Azure Marketplace Terms, however ... when I run my code it error's out saying that:
blah blah subscription / offer blah already exists - to be managed via Terraform this resource needs to be imported into the State.

Is there a way in Terraform that I can write my module or CALL my module to only run if the Terms haven't already been accepted. I can do this standing on my head in PowerShell, but cannot work out how to do it in Terraform.

Kind regards,

Dave.

Comment: TF does not provide any functionality to check if something exists or not. You would have to develop custom solution for that.

Comment: Thanks @Marcin that's what I was thinking was the case .. but at the same time kinda hoping that it wasn't and I just hadn't found it yet. :